# ¿Hay alguna manera de limpiar los valores de un diccionario de python?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Estoy intentando crear un diccionario en `python3`, el cual contiene más valores que claves. La idea es la siguiente:

Tengo las siguientes listas:

```py
claves = [1,2,3]
datos = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Al realizar lo siguiente:

```py
diccionariovacio={c:0 for c in claves}
diccionariolleno={c:v for c,v in zip(diccionariovacio,datos)}
```

Solo toma los primeros tres elementos, es decir, crea el siguiente diccionario:

```py
diccionariolleno={1:'1',2:'2',3:'3'}
```

Por lo tanto, mi pregunta es si de alguna manera, se podría crear el mismo diccionario con las mismas claves pero con el resto de los elementos de la tabla datos, teniendo en cuenta que es para escribir los datos de los diccionarios en un fichero con formato csv.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes añadir un ejemplo de cómo querrías que quedase?

Comment: Quería 2 diccionarios distintos que usasen unas claves introducidas por un usuario, es decir, si el usuario introduce las claves 1,2,3 y 4 así como los datos 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 y 8, diese lugar a: ```d1={1:1,2:2,2:3,2:4} y d2={1:5,2:6,3:7,4:8}```

Comment: deberías darle a [edit] para explicar en la propia pregunta, en lugar de en los comentarios. También es bueno indicar qué has intentado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si entendí correctamente. Creo que la idea que persigues es la de crear un diccionario que itere por unas claves dadas, asignando a cada clave un valor tomado de otra lista, hasta que la lista de claves se agote. Cuando esto suceda, crear un segundo diccionario que itere otra vez por la misma lista de claves, y continúe asignando a esas claves los restantes valores de la lista de datos, etc.

Supongo además que cada uno de esos diccionarios nuevos que se van creando se irán guardando en una lista.

Si es esto lo que buscabas, el siguiente código haría lo que pides:

```
claves = [1, 2, 3, 4]
datos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


resultado = []   # Lista que contendrá los diccionarios creados
dict_aux = {}    # Diccionario que de momento vamos construyendo

for indice, dato in enumerate(datos):
  i = indice % len(claves)     # Reciclar índices
  if i == 0 and dict_aux:      # Si hemos empezado a reciclar índices
    # Añadir diccionario anterior al resultado, y crear uno nuevo
    resultado.append(dict_aux)
    dict_aux = {}

  # Añadir elemento al diccionario en curso
  dict_aux[claves[i]] = dato

# Al terminar, añadir el último diccionario en curso al resultado, si no está vacío
if dict_aux:
  resultado.append(dict_aux)
```

El resultado en este caso sería una lista con tres diccionarios:

```
[
  {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}, 
  {1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 8}, 
  {1: 9, 2: 10}
]
```

## Segunda opción

En cualquier caso, es un poco extraño tu requisito, y vería más normal crear un solo diccionario con las claves 1, 2, 3, 4, pero de modo que en cada clave pueda contener varios valores (una lista de ellos). Así, la clave 1 contendría los valores 1, 5 y 9, etc.

Para este otro enfoque la cosa puede quedar más corta haciendo uso de funcionalidades de las librerías `itertools` y `defaultdict`:

```
from itertools import cycle
from collections import defaultdict

resultado = defaultdict(list)
for clave, dato in zip(cycle(claves), datos):
  resultado[clave].append(dato)
```

En este caso el resultado no es una lista de diccionarios, sino un diccionario cuyos valores son listas. Para el ejemplo anterior el diccionario resultante sería:

```
{
  1: [1, 5, 9], 
  2: [2, 6, 10], 
  3: [3, 7], 
  4: [4, 8]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) tienes la respuesta de por que te sucede eso. Ahi se explica que en la función `zip(a, b)`, en caso de que `a` y `b` tengan longitudes distintas, el iterador con menos elementos decide la longitud del nuevo iterador. Por otro lado, si entiendo lo que quieres, no se puede crear un diccionario en el cual se repitan las claves. Por ejemplo, nunca vas a lograr algo como esto.

```py
x = {1: "1", 2: "2", 1: "3"}
```

Lo cual, si entendí bien, es lo que pretendes. Bueno, déjame saber si respondo a tu inquietud. Si entendí mal tu propósito, hásmelo saber también.

Comment: Realmente lo que quería hacer era  crear 2 diccionarios distintos pero con las mismas claves.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes aplicar la misma función pero usando el resto de valores:

```
diccionariolleno2={c:v for c,v in zip(diccionariovacio,datos[len(claves):])}
```

Eso creará un diccionario con:

```
>>> diccionariolleno2
{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6}
```